# unable to update npm install -g npm@latest

Tags: npm, erpnext

I'm prgarding erpnext

```
frappe@ubuntu:~/frappe-bench$ npm install -g npm@latest
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/frappe/.npm/_logs/2023-06-30T12_01_16_201Z-debug-0.log

npx npm install -g npm@latest
npm cache clean --force
npm install latest-version
yarn global add npm@latest
yarn --insecure global add npm@latest
```

I tried all these

but getting error,

I wants to update npm

Comment: `self signed certificate in certificate chain` suggests that somewhere on the way to `registry.npmjs.org` there's a self-signed (a.k.a "bad") certificate. That *could* theoretically be a problem with the site itself, but that's unlikely (I can reach it just fine with a proper cert), so the odds are that you're using a proxy that's using an unsigned certificate. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following helped resolve the issue:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

This command disabled strict SSL verification, removing the self signed certificate error.

This does not usually happen in normal environments, could be because of an antivirus or proxy which used a self signed certificate.

Comment: This question is also a duplicate. I'm not trying to be rude, but please, try searching for similar questions before asking.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me...

Using Ubuntu

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs